# Log into remote computer using C#

Tags: c#, windows, authentication

I'm working on an application to start up the various servers and workstations in a system from one central server.  As part of this, I need to log in to several workstations (currently running Windows 7) so that their startup applications can load.

I have tried running the startup applications remotely (using both a WMI approach and a scheduled tasks approach), but that has not resulted in the application fully initializing.

Does anyone have any suggestions on other angles I could try?  Note that I cannot use PSExec on these systems.

UPDATE:  To isolate the specific problem, is there a way to non-interactively remotely log in to a server as a specified user so that its startup applications execute as if the user just logged in on the workstation manually?

Comment: `... that has not resulted in the application fully initializing.` - do you have more info on that? Error message? Code you used to run the applications remotely?

Comment: The process was running (according to Task Manager) but the application didn't show up when I logged in on that computer normally (or if I was already logged in when I ran the command to start the process).  My research indicated that that was normal for WMI, but the process was not setting up what it was supposed to on startup.

Comment: For the Scheduled Tasks approach, if I was not logged in with the appropriate account on the target computer when I set the task for, the task scheduler showed a message indicating that the operation was not performed because the user was not logged in and no such service existed.

Comment: Then it works as expected. What do you want to achieve? If you want to run something on background with no user logged in, use services.